# Difference between two hexadecimal numbers

Tags: hex, decimal, bin

I have two hexadecimal numbers: **12C** (300 in decimal) and **78** (120 in decimal). I want to calculate the difference between these two numbers without using their decimal equivalence and without using the minus sign (-). How can I do this?

Comment: As in, in your head?

Comment: subtraction between the two hexadecimals (12C - 78)